# Create video from single images

Tags: ffmpeg

I have these Images in a folder (~/Downloads/output_frames)
I want to use the command I got from https://github.com/nihui/dain-ncnn-vulkan

`ffmpeg -framerate 48 -i output_frames/%06d.png -i audio.m4a -c:a copy -crf 20 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

[image: My files are named like this]

I get this error:

`[image2 @ 0x14681b800] Could find no file with path 'output_frames/%06d.png' and index in the range 0-4`

`output_frames/%06d.png: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%08d.png` as there are 8 digits.